# When changing the Authentication of an app in IIS 7, an app on a different site changes with it

Tags: authentication, iis-7, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am having a problem with my auth settings in IIS.

I have several sites running, some with forms, and some with windows auth.

Both of them have a Management app (pointing to the same folder, because that's where the products core is)

For some reason I cannot have different Authentication setting on it. When I set the App of the Forms App(Site A)  to Forms, the Windows Auth App (Site B) also enables the Forms Auth setting. And vice versa...

I have both of the sites running on the same App-Pool. But a colleague of mine has the same problem and he has different app-pools for either site.

Could someone perhaps explain what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication Mode is configured in web.config. When both sites are in the same physical directory both sites are reconfigured.
Copy the directory to maintain two different web.config or use location tag in a parent virtual directory web.config.